Finding an undefined point using collinear points.
If I have 3 points that are collinear and wish to find a fourth point that isn't collinear and isn't defined, do I do some form of projection or is there another approach I can take to find this fourth point?

How do you feel about "1: pick random coordinates for fourth point, 2: check in new point is on line, 3a: if so, go back to step 1, else 3b: you have a noncollinear new point."  Perhaps you don't want to coordinatize?

Lol, I am open to picking a random point. However, its more than just picking a random point at this point

Rotate one of the given points (say, $P$) about another ($O$), through an angle that isn't a multiple of $180^\circ$, to get non-collinear point $P'$. Optionally, also (keeping $O$ fixed) stretch $OP'$ by a non-zero scale factor.

Thank you, I really appreciate your input I will try this method in the morning. I was thinking about doing a translation as well. Let me know what you think.
